# Python idle not opening text file with open ()

Tags: python-3.x

being a few weeks old coder,I am unable to make python read my file despite the code and .txt file being in the same folder

```
highest_score=0
result_f = open("results.text")
for line in result_f:
    if float (line)>highest_score:
        highest_score = float(line)
        result_f.close()
        print("the highest score:")
        print(highest_score)
```

and result is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\-mu.py", line 2, in <module>
result_f = open("results.text")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'results.text'
```

Please help

Comment: Obviously, the file does not exist in the directory you **execute** the script.

Comment: An honest mistake and easy to make. Either cd to the folder that your text file is in, or include the whole path when you do open()

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to open the file `result.text`. The error returned is that Python Idle cannot find that file. I notice that you mentioned a `.txt` file but in your code you try to open a `.text` file.
So I would suggest you to check wheter your file extension is `.txt` or `.text` and, in case, correct.

If the error still persists, try to give the full path to the open command. For example:

```
result_f = open("/Users/Joe/Desktop/results.text")
```

Both Windows and Mac OS give, somewhere when right-clicking on the file, the full path (among other information).

Comment: You're right, I was putting the wrong extension. With .txt, it worked, thanks :)

Comment: Hmm. Even .txt doesn't work for me. Ill keep trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, where I was trying to read a file in idle but it couldn't find the path. What worked for me:

1. Enter the full path of the file with the extension
2. Instead of the native path writing style in windows i.e. (`D:\python\sample.txt`)
   use (`D:/python/sample.txt`)

It worked out for me in Windows 7, IDLE 3.6.4 and also works on Windows 8